# Big Data and machine learning to Predictive analytics

Tags: machine-learning, big-data

This is the first time I post a question here. I am a newbie researcher and want to write a report about Big Data influence on machine learning to improve predictive analytics. I looked through Google for any relevant study shed the light on this subject, but what I found only briefed articles that are not suited to be good resource. Is there any resource I can use through the web as I looked through different libraries and didn't find any good resources relevant? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

["The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data"](http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/35179.pdf) is an insightful article, written by by some Google researchers in 2010.

If you search for [articles that have cited this](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?cites=7014969931485742163&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), you'll find plenty of stuff to read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, I liked The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data" report. It is really knowledgeable

Answer (score 0):

Predictive Analysis is important to web analytics and useful for predicting what may happen in the future.

You may find this video helpful about [Predictive Analytics](http://www.decisivedata.net/blog/what-is-predictive-analytics).

They offer a ton of helpful insight on how predictive analytics fit into the spectrum of analytics and data science, especially when it comes to big data!

Hopefully, this will help clarify!

Best Wishes, Bethany

Answer (score 0):

Big data is huge in helping accelerate predictive analytics. More specifically, data companies today are using people data to power machine learning algorithms and predictive analytics.

So how do companies incorporate data to improve predictive analytics?

1. They use data providers to clean and enrich their contact data
   adding data points including name, title, phone number, email,
   social URLs, and more.
2. They implement their enriched data into their platform, training
   their algorithms to find, and engage customers.
3. The algorithms provide data and results that enable predictive
   analytics to generate insights.